# Path for resources html difference between "images" and "../images"

Tags: html

I have a html located at www.domain/folderOne. My images path's at www.domain/images.

I found out that the file mywebpage.html located at www.domain/folderOne can get the images displayed with either

```
<img src="../images/7.jpg" alt="Text" style="width: 800px; height:400px; " id="text">
```

and

```
<img src="images/texts/6/7.jpg" alt="Text" style="width: 800px; height:400px; " id="text">
```

I don't know why both work. Could anyone provide an answer? As an extra information, I am making the html file change the location displayed in address bar after it is loaded with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    history.pushState(null, null, '../SuperWeb');
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '../SuperWeb');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I see. Ok, thank you, maybe you'd like to post it as an answer, since it's the best -and only- answer given :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely either have a symbolic link in the directory tree that stores your web assets on the server, or a web server mapping (e.g., a rewrite rule) that maps calls from one URI to the other. Hard to know without knowing more about your server setup, but it's not an intrinsic feature of HTML. I will point out that it's a good practice to use site-relative links (e.g., `/path/img.jpg`) rather than document relative (as you specify above), as it makes it hard to migrate content to different directories.